# How to display a view from a module in the view of another module?

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm actually working for a project using PRISM and Unity and I'm encountering a problem with the interaction between modules.

The architecture of the project looks actually like this :

```
App
 -AppModuleA (Layout)
 -AppModuleB
 -AppModuleC
 -AppModuleD
```

The application looks actually like this :

[image: Application's schema]

If I add a module to the main region, it is added as a pane as the mainregion is a XamDockManager from Infragistics. It will also call AppModuleA everytime as it the main layout, so it will instantiate it several times.

What I want to do is actually adding to AppModuleA's XamDockManager an AppModuleB's (or C or D) View displaying a ContentPane, How can I manage to do that ?

I read the PRISM tutorial [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921153(v=pandp.40).aspx) but I didnt find how to do it (even if it is said it's possible on part 8)

> Furthermore, in a composite application, which is composed from loosely coupled modules, the views will often be defined in separate modules. Individual views will need to be identified in a way that does not introduce tight coupling and dependencies between modules.

Any help would be appreciated, don't hesitate to ask me for more informations if you find out it's not enough.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, if I get it, you want a view from AppModuleB appear inside a view from AppModuleB? Put a region in AppModuleA's view and have AppModuleB inject its view in that region (they both have to know the region's name, of course, that should be defined in an assembly known to both modules).

Comment: @Haukinger Thank you for your answer. If I put a region in AppModuleA's view, can I still instantiate this module several times, each tab displaying the region with different modules (B, C, D etc...) inside ?

Comment: Regions need to have unique names... even if not, how would your modules B, C, D know which instance of A they should use?

Comment: Then can I, for each time I instantiate AppModuleA, give a different name to the region ? 
It seems like it's possible according to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec35)

Comment: "Adding a Region by Using Code

[...]The following code example shows how to add a region to a control from the code-behind file.[...]" So module B adds a view to shell within a view created by module A? Then module B can pass the name of the region it will inject his own view in into the service that creates the layout to inject into the shell, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to clarify some terminology.  You aren't adding a module to your regions.  So you don't add AppModuleA to your mainregion.  Instead your application will load modules into it's app domain which will give you access to the views and logic within the module.  Now, you inject your Views into regions using view injection, view discovery, or navigation.  Your modules do not have to know about each other in order to do this.

For multiple instances of your views which happen to contain regions themselves, you'll have to use what's called a scoped region.

You should watch these courses to help you understand these concepts better:

- https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-introduction
- https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-showing-multiple-shells
- https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-mastering-tabcontrol

Those will give you the knowledge you need to fully understand what you are trying to build.